# calling listbox from different function in python with tkinter

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, object, tkinter

I'm trying to add and remove items from a listbox but I'm getting the following error:

```
files = self.fileList()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

How can I access this list if I can't call it? I tried to use it as a global variable but maybe I was using it incorrectly.  I want to be able to take items from that listbox and when a button is pressed, add them to another listbox.

```
class Actions:

def openfile(self): #select a directory to view files
    directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir='.')
    self.directoryContents(directory)


def filename(self):
    Label (text='Please select a directory').pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)

files = []
fileListSorted = []
fileList = []

#display the contents of the directory
def directoryContents(self, directory): #displays two listBoxes containing items
    scrollbar = Scrollbar() #left scrollbar - display contents in directory
    scrollbar.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y) 

    scrollbarSorted = Scrollbar() #right scrollbar - display sorted files 
    scrollbarSorted.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

    #files displayed in the left listBox
    global fileList
    fileList = Listbox(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set) 
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        fileList.insert(END, filename)
    fileList.pack(side =LEFT, fill = BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command = fileList.yview)


    global fileListSorted #this is for the filelist in the right window. contains the values the user has selected
    fileListSorted = Listbox(yscrollcommand = scrollbarSorted.set) #second listbox (button will send selected files to this window)
    fileListSorted.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
    scrollbarSorted.config(command = fileListSorted.yview)

    selection = fileList.curselection() #select the file
    b = Button(text="->", command=lambda:self.moveFile(fileList.curselection()))#send the file to moveFile to be added to fileListSorted
    b.pack(pady=5, padx =20)


def moveFile(self,File):
    files = self.fileList()
    insertValue = int(File[0]) #convert the item to integer
    insertName = self.fileList[insertValue] #get the name of the file to be inserted
    fileListSorted.insert(END,str(insertName)) #insertthe value to the fileList array
```

I changed files to the following to see if files was setting properly and it returned an empty array

```
files = self.fileList
print files
#prints []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialise `self.fileList` (nor `fileListSorted`). 
When you write in `directoryContents`

```
global fileList
fileList = Listbox(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
...
```

you work on a global variable called `fileList`. You could either use `self.fileList` everywhere (or add `global fileList` in all your function, and thus use `fileList`).

*However, I am skeptical of your use of classes, you should try to understand object-oriented concepts and their implementation in python, or ignore these concepts for the moment.*

---

**Edit**

I have tried to run your code and you might also change the line

```
insertName = self.fileList[insertValue]
```

by

```
insertName = self.fileList.get(insertValue)
```

`fileList` i a widget and every Tkinter widgets use dictionnary notation for properties (such as `self.fileList['background']`).

Note that get take either a number, or a string containing a number and thus your conversion on above line is useless. Also note that you can get the whole list through `get(0,END)`.

Comment: `fileList` is your Tkinter Listbox on the left. You create it through `Listbox(...)`. From what do you want to distinguish it ?